# Output is NA when the data is there

Tags: r

in my dataset below, I am trying to find the `Pressure` at which `PAR` is the same or less than 0.01% of the max `PAR`

The max PAR is 588.46 and it's found at a pressure of 3 but when I use the code below, it says NA for the pressure at which 0.01 of the maximum is found. but in the data, you can see that it should state pressure of 54 (where PAR is 5.72)

It works for many other files but just a handful it doesn't. I have na.rm=TRUE so im guessing it's ok with NA's in the datafile. what is causing it to return an NA instead of 54?

```
structure(list(PAR = c(79, 374.99, NA, 588.46, 390.78, 351.5, 
298.24, 246.64, 240.41, NA, 189.88, 167.27, 163.61, 152.5, 131.08, 
156.68, 139.7, 121.61, 107.22, 96.73, 89.56, 83.34, 77.06, 70.82, 
65.65, 67.04, 54.24, 51.22, 49.62, 46.63, 44.26, 42.66, 40.75, 
39.72, 29.53, 31.6, 30.68, 28.2, 25.73, 23.77, 21.84, 19.94, 
18.08, 16.39, 14.79, 13.44, 12.31, 11.3, 10.34, 9.38, 8.61, 8, 
7.41, 6.54, 5.72, 5.37, 5.02, 4.69, 4.36, 4.04, 3.75, 3.47, 3.22, 
3, 2.81, 2.64, 2.48, 2.35, 2.22, 2.1, 1.98, 1.87, 1.76, 1.66, 
1.57, 1.48, 1.39, 1.32, 1.24, 1.23, 1.11, 1.07, 1.01, 0.95, 0.89, 
0.85, 0.8, 0.76, 0.72, 0.7, 0.66, 0.64, 0.61, 0.57, 0.55, 0.52, 
0.49, 0.47, 0.44, 0.4), Pressure = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 
40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 
56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 
72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 
88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")

miss <- function(x) ifelse(is.finite(x),x,NA)
d.depths <- test %>% 
summarize(
euphotic=miss(min(Pressure[PAR <= 0.01*max(PAR)], Inf, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Your code is not complete, it ends with a comma. Please correct it.

Comment: Are you looking for the `na.rm = TRUE` argument of several functions like `max()`, `min()`, `sum()`, ..., i.e., `xyzzy[xyzzy$PAR <= .01 * max(xyzzy$PAR, na.rm = TRUE), "Pressure"]`

Comment: I am looking for the minimum pressure where PAR is 0.1% of the maximum PAR value. And I want it to recognise that there are NA's in the datafile. I dont want to know where there are NA's just the minimum pressure where PAR is 0.1% of max value.

Comment: I suspect this is answered by my comment. Are you looking for the row index of those?

Comment: `min(xyzzy$Pressure[xyzzy$PAR <= .01 * max(xyzzy$PAR, na.rm = TRUE)], na.rm = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, filter by the appropriate criteria to get the row(s) you want.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

test %>% 
  filter(PAR <= 0.01*max(PAR, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(Pressure == min(Pressure, na.rm = TRUE))
#>    PAR Pressure
#> 1 5.72       54
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you! I needed to put a second na.rm =TRUE inside the PAR as well as you suggested and that worked!